# Distributed computing: Boomerang.js issues installing using npm

Tags: javascript, npm-install, distributed-computing, grid-computing

I am doing a project about grid computing using Javascript. Boomerang.js is a middleware for distributed computing, and I wish to install its server(https://github.com/bergos/boomerang-server).

When I try to do so, errors occure when using npm install to install dependencies.

I tried following the install guide on this website (https://www.boomerangjs.org). This leads me to giving the following commands to the terminal.

```
npm install boomerang-server
cd node_modules/boomerang-server
npm start
```

I get an error running `npm install boomerang-server`, and the folder `boomerang-server` is not created as exptected. The error-log is found below.
I would appreciate some guidance on how to solve the problem. Thank you in advance!

```
C:\Users\Bruger>npm install boomerang-server
npm WARN deprecated rdf-interfaces@0.1.1: This package is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version of rdf-ext.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated xmldom@0.1.19: Deprecated due to CVE-2021-21366 resolved in 0.5.0
npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.3: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated connect@2.30.2: connect 2.x series is deprecated
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\Bruger\\node_modules\\boomerang-client',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\Bruger\node_modules\boomerang-client\node_modules'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\Bruger\\node_modules\\boomerang-client\\node_modules'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Bruger\node_modules\contextify
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.14.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.0 found at "C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:369:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:390:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:427:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Bruger\node_modules\contextify
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-15T13_18_16_053Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get an error running npm install boomerang-server, and the folder boomerang-server is not created as exptected. I would appreciate some guidance on how to solve the problem. Thank you in advance!

Unfortunately, I think the best solution would be to look for some other software for your project than boomerang.

[`boomerang-server` hasn't been updated in 8 years.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/boomerang-server) Chances that you can run it these days (especially with Node 18) are very slim.

The [boomerang-server GitHub repository](https://github.com/bergos/boomerang-server) has been archived in mid-2022, and the [boomerangjs Twitter account](https://twitter.com/boomerangjs) last tweeted in 2015. The project seems dead as a doorstop.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!

I understand that it's an old project, but is there any specific things in Node 18, that makes it unusable?
Been trying to search for an alternative coded in Javascript, but it doesn't seem like there's much out there. Do you know why? Also, do you know any other small programs utilizing grid computing?

Comment: The specific error you're seeing is that it's trying to compile the `contextify` binary Node.js extension, but you don't have a working Visual Studio. Even if you did, it's about 100% likely that a version of contextify circa 8 years ago won't compile against Node 18's interfaces. You _could_ have a chance with a 2015-era Node.js (that's about version 4 to 6) in a Docker container (so you don't need to install Visual Studio)...

Comment: As for the other questions, well, no, I don't know.